# Error 1215 foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm still very new to this, so have patience while I learn the rules. 
I'm having issues with mysql script, it gives me a very common 1215 error (cannot create foreign key)

I've already checked the data types, and that the foreign keys reference primary keys, and it still isn't working.

[The script. Issue is with the two final foreign keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7TjN.png)

Answer (score 1):

Must be declare like this:

must declare first the Foreign key:

```
Create table(id ... , foreignKEY INT NOT NULL,
 Constraint FOREIGN KEY(foreignKEY) REFERENCES  table_refered(it primary key));
```

// foreignKEY- must be declare first as a column , and then after that declare it as `FOREIGN KEY` GOOD LUCK.

Answer (score 0):

You just made a mistake in the syntax for the referenced table and column.

You wrote for example:

```
foreign key (rm_id) references roomate.rm_id,
```

It should be:

```
foreign key (rm_id) references roomate(rm_id),
```

Syntax is documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

You mistake when assign the REFERENCE `key` to the `PERCENTAGE` table. The reference key should be like this.

```
FOREIGN KEY (RM_ID) REFERENCES ROOMMATE(RM_Id)
FOREIGN KEY (ITM_Id) REFERENCES ITEM(ITM_Id)
```

Instead of this:

```
FOREIGN KEY (RM_ID) REFERENCES ROOMMATE.RM_Id
FOREIGN KEY (ITM_Id) REFERENCES ITEM.ITM_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice you haven't assigned names to you primary key/unique constraints and you can omit them from your foreign keys too. Also, for simple (single-column) keys, you can declare them in-line with the column declaration e.g. snipped example:

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM ( ITM_ID INT(3) NOT NULL UNIQUE );

CREATE TABLE PERCENTAGE ( ITM_ID INT(3) NOT NULL REFERENCES ITEM ( ITM_ID ) );
```